# finding the points of a triangle from a rectangle

Tags: geometry

if I have 2 points (x,y) (x,y) I know how to make a rectangle from those points but how do I get the points of a triangle?

I need some help if its possible and how to find them

Comment: Not enough information sorry. How are you making a rectangle from the two points? How does that relate to your triangle?

Comment: Do you mean (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)? Try typing \$(x\_1,  y\_1)\$ and it will look like $(x_1, y_1)$. Two points only define a line segment. A line segment does not define a triangle (nor does it define a rectangle).

Comment: @DavidDiaz well if $x_1\neq x_2, y_1\neq y_2$ then the points indeed may span a rectangle. This is a parametrization of an *axis aligned bounding box* sometimes used in computer graphics

Comment: You can create infinite rectangles and triangles. Are you looking for squares and equilateral triangles?